# Calculating Percentages Error

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-calculation

I am trying to fix this percent calculation, however it is just stumping me today.

Here is the code:

```
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries($form['id'], $search_criteria);

$score = 0;
$max = 0;
$percentage = array();
if(!empty($entries)) {
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        $score = GFSurvey::get_field_score($form_fields, $entry);
        $max = end($form_fields['choices']);

        if(empty($max['score'])) {
            unset($form_fields['choices'][key($form_fields['choices'])]);
            $max = end($form_fields['choices']);
            }
        $max = $max['score'];
        $percentage[] = ($score / $max ) * 100;
        }
    }

$average = round(array_sum($percentage) / count($percentage), 2);
```

I have the form and i have Not Applicable radio buttons on the form. When a client fills out the form, sometimes on certain questions they need to be N/A because they do not apply and that does not need to counted in the overall total score.

So that is the report generated which the % is incorrect. That percent should read: 94%. In this picture you will see if you click on the graph you can see this:

[Graph Once Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yjr4.png)

It is showing the people who answered this question, and there are 20. There are a total of 5 max points for each person, or in this case I have the N/A box set for blank, which returns 0. What it is doing is totaling all the possible points which are 100. (20 people and 5 max points)

What I need it to do is **NOT** count the blank fields and in return give me for example in the image [Graph Once Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yjr4.png) there are only 5 people that answered so max points are 25. the total points is 23.5 so 23.5 / 25.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code ? The total percentage of answered questions is in variable `$total_percentage`.

```
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries($form['id'], $search_criteria);

$score = 0;
$max = 0;
$total_max = $total_score = 0;
$percentage = array();
if(!empty($entries)) {
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {

        $score = GFSurvey::get_field_score($form_fields, $entry);
        $max = end($form_fields['choices']);

        if(empty($max['score'])) {
            unset($form_fields['choices'][key($form_fields['choices'])]);
            $max = end($form_fields['choices']);
            }
        $max = $max['score'];

        if ($max) {
            $total_score += $score;
            $total_max += $max;
        }

        $percentage[] = ($score / $max ) * 100;
        }
    }

$average = round(array_sum($percentage) / count($percentage), 2);
$total_percentage = ($total_max > 0) ? round($total_score/$total_max/100, 2) : 0;
```

Comment: This didnt work. Here is the file: http://myboxv.com/file/1456954898_reporting-customersatisfaction

Comment: But thank you so much for trying this means so much! :D

Comment: Can you give more information ? What exactly didnt work ? Do you have any PHP error ? Or the number was wrong ?

Comment: There were no changes to the number it stayed at 23.5%.

Comment: I also added the php file itself if that helps. :)